# How to use subreport across multiple reports or create parent report from subreport?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, crystal-reports, report

I have a Crystal Report called MainReport in Visual Studio, which also has a subreport. The contents of the subreport are the header details but now this is required across a couple of other reports.

Is there any way to re-use the subreport across other reports or a way to change it from a subreport to being its own parent report?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

According to the thread [save subreport as an individual report](https://answers.sap.com/questions/5196296/save-subreport-as-an-individual-report.html) from SAP:

> This option is only available in the full version of Crystal Report Designer.
>   It's not available in the .NET IDE Report designer.

Answer (score 0):

Open the sub report and go to `file ---> save subreport as` and save the report in any of the location.

now you can use the sub report as the main report or inside any main report.

If this is not your requirement let me know.

Comment: There isn't a save subreport as option, only save as which saves the entire report, not just the subreport

Comment: no... first open the sub report and then you can see save subreport as

Comment: Is this even within VS? If it is, a screenshot would be great. I don't seem to have the same options as you

Comment: I don't have expertise in VS but if you see from CR as standalone tool then this will work.

Comment: I mentioned in the original post I was using VS, also tagged it with VS. My answer to the question tells others that this isn't possible in VS without CR standalone.

Comment: I thought functionality may be available...if my answer doesn't help you ... please ignore it

Answer (score 0):

As above suggest, this is the only solution. Other wise you just create a new one and then use it as a sub-report to another report.

Good to install Crystal report as per your .net framework or your IDE.